# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings. checkout

Tags: custom-theme, magento-2.1.10

I am getting knockout js error on checkout page so order summary not display to customers at checkout page in order summary section. can anyone suggest how can I debug this.

[image]

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings.
Bindings value: mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', , 'active': true}}
Message: Unexpected token ,
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624)
    at createBindingsStringEvaluatorViaCache (knockout.js:2615)
    at ko.bindingProvider.parseBindingsString (knockout.js:2601)
    at ko.bindingProvider.getBindingAccessors (knockout.js:2583)
    at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:2931)
    at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1946)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2929)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:2854)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid json `{'openedState': 'active', , 'active': true}`
Notice the 2 commas with just a blank space between them.
Check where this is generated and why do you get an empty space.

Comment: Thanks it works for me I had an issue with Magento_Checkout\web\template\summary\cart-items.html  there is an blank space and extra comma was exist in the code after remove the extra comma it works